# Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /ckeditorupload/ in django?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

When i try to upload an image in the admin panel of django, i get this `Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /ckeditorupload/` i have this result in my console.
here my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
# Create your models here.

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    #content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = RichTextUploadingField()
    #image = models.ImageField(upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/') #
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my views

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
    class PostList(generic.ListView):
            queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
            template_name = 'index.html'
    class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
            model = Post
            template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

I tried to exempt the CSRF but i get same issues, & when i delete the middlewareCsrf it's dont works too, since i'm using the admin django and not a custom post method, i dont know where to pass the {{ csrf_token }}

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago, it was as if all of a sudden there was no `csrf_token` available anymore in the user session. After a bit of tinkering this solved it.

import:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
```

in the view:

```
csrf_token = get_token(request)

context = {
    "csrf_token": csrf_token,
}
```

In the template I still use `{% csrf_token %}`, but I also make some API calls in JavaScript and in those ones I instead used directly the token that i passed through the context -> `{{ csrf_token }}`

Comment: i get  `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`  i added the import & the text below you suggested to the views, actually i'm trying to create a mini blog where i have one model "Post", and i create a post to a blog from the admin panel so idk how to implement that since i'm new to django

Comment: You have to do this inside your view, where you have access to the `request` object. If you dont have the `request` explicitly available try with `self.request`